# I want to select the Last 10 Average Weights

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query but when I include my CapturedDateTime and IsOutOfSpec columns then it returns multiple rows but I only want one record to be returned that displays the averages of the last 10 records. So it must return the average PartWeight, average SprueWeight and average Bom Weight for a specified stock code.

```
--Last 10 Average Report
SELECT Top 10 c.StockCode,i.LongDesc,
AVG(c.PartWeightGram) AS 'Part Weight Average',
AVG(c.SprueWeightGram) AS 'Sprue Weight Average' ,
AVG(c.TolerancePercentage) AS 'Tolerance Average' , 
AVG(c.BomWeightKG * 1000) AS 'Bom Weight Average' ,
AVG(c.PartWeightGram + (c.SprueWeightGram / 2)) - (c.BomWeightKG)  AS 'Variance To Syspro Average', 
AVG((((((c.PartWeightGram + c.SprueWeightGram  / 2))) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) / (c.BomWeightKG * 1000))  * 100) AS 'VarianceToSysproPct'
FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c 
LEFT JOIN [Mercury].[EncoreCompanyA].dbo.InvMaster i ON  c.StockCode = i.StockCode
WHERE c.StockCode='000-256966-020' And Deleted = 'False'
GROUP BY c.StockCode,i.LongDesc,c.BomWeightKG
ORDER BY c.StockCode DESC
```

This is my Table:

```
SELECT [ComponentWeightCheckID]
      ,[EmpID]
      ,[StockCode]
      ,[Process]
      ,[PartWeightGram]
      ,[SprueWeightGram]
      ,[BomWeightKG]
      ,[TolerancePercentage]
      ,[AssetID]
      ,[CapturedDateTime]
      ,[Hostname]
      ,[Username]
      ,[IsOutOfSpec]
      ,[Tool]
      ,[Deleted]
  FROM [dbo].[tblComponentWeightCheck]
```

Sample Data:

```
SELECT  Top 10 c.StockCode,i.LongDesc AS 'Description', 
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG(PartWeightGram) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode ) AS  'Part Weight Average',
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG([SprueWeightGram]) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode  ) AS 'Sprue Weight Average',
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG(c.TolerancePercentage) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode   ) AS 'Tolerance Average',
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG([BomWeightKG]) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode   ) AS 'Bom Weight Average',
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG((c.PartWeightGram + (c.SprueWeightGram / 2)) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode   ) AS 'Variance To Syspro Average',
(SELECT  TOP 10 AVG((((((c.PartWeightGram + c.SprueWeightGram  / 2))) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) / (c.BomWeightKG * 1000))  * 100) FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020' GROUP BY c.StockCode   ) AS 'Variance To Syspro & Average'                 
FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c
LEFT JOIN [Mercury].[EncoreCompanyA].dbo.InvMaster i ON  c.StockCode = i.StockCode
WHERE c.StockCode = '000-256966-020'
AND CONVERT(Date, c.CapturedDateTime) Between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-05-24'
GROUP BY c.StockCode, i.LongDesc
```

[This image shows the result of the above query.It only returns 1 row which it should but it is missing my CapturedDateTime AND IsOutOfSpec columns, as soon as i include those then it returns multiple records which i don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27dGo.png)

Comment: "Last 10" depending on which order?

Comment: DESC Order @Tyron78 .

Comment: DESC Order by what? You want to group by stock code, filter on one single stock code - so if there are multiple entries per stock code, you will have to define how to sort these,,,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question clearer.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for you help @Tyron78 but i don't understand your query as it is too complex and when i tried running it i got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the `LEFT JOIN` is not needed -- it would seem odd to have stock codes that are not in the inventory master.

You can do this pretty easily using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT Top 10 i.StockCode, i.LongDesc,
       AVG(c.PartWeightGram) AS Part_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.SprueWeightGram) AS Sprue_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.TolerancePercentage) AS Tolerance_Average, 
       AVG(c.BomWeightKG * 1000) AS Bom_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.PartWeightGram + (c.SprueWeightGram / 2)) - (c.BomWeightKG)  AS Variance_To_Syspro_Average, 
       AVG((((((c.PartWeightGram + c.SprueWeightGram  / 2))) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) / (c.BomWeightKG * 1000))  * 100) AS VarianceToSysproPct
FROM [Mercury].[EncoreCompanyA].dbo.InvMaster i CROSS APPLY 
     (SELECT TOP (10) c.*
      FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c 
      WHERE c.StockCode = i.StockCode
      ORDER BY c.CapturedDateTime DESC
     ) c
WHERE i.StockCode = '000-256966-020' AND Deleted = 'False'
GROUP BY i.StockCode, i.LongDesc, c.BomWeightKG
ORDER BY i.StockCode DESC;
```

For performance, I recommend indexes on `tblComponentWeightCheck(StockCode, CapturedDateTime DESC)` and `InvMaster(StockCode)`.

Comment: Thanks this works, but i need to include columns CapturedDateTime and IsOutOfSpec in my select as well but as soon as i do this then I have to include it by my Group By also but then it returns multiple records where I just want it to return 1 record

Comment: @coder101 . . . (1) That is not the question you asked here and this answers the question you *asked*.  (2) You need to figure out how to combine them . . . `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or some other aggregation function.  If you can't figure it out, then ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.  I think you should be able to simplify the query as well for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your query, you should use a window function and a subquery instead of top 10. Following an example. However, you will have to provide the sorting criteria for the ROW_NUMBER() in order to define your "TOP 10"...

```
--Last 10 Average Report
SELECT c.StockCode,c.LongDesc,
AVG(c.PartWeightGram) AS 'Part Weight Average',
AVG(c.SprueWeightGram) AS 'Sprue Weight Average' ,
AVG(c.TolerancePercentage) AS 'Tolerance Average' , 
AVG(c.BomWeightKG * 1000) AS 'Bom Weight Average' ,
AVG(c.PartWeightGram + (c.SprueWeightGram / 2)) - (c.BomWeightKG)  AS 'Variance To Syspro Average', 
AVG((((((c.PartWeightGram + c.SprueWeightGram  / 2))) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) / (c.BomWeightKG * 1000))  * 100) AS 'VarianceToSysproPct'
FROM (
  SELECT c.StockCode
    ,i.LongDesc
    ,c.PartWeightGram
    ,c.SprueWeightGram
    ,c.TolerancePercentage
    ,c.BomWeightKG
    ,c.PartWeightGram
    ,c.PartWeightGram
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.StockCode ORDER BY ...) AS rn
  FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c 
  LEFT JOIN [Mercury].[EncoreCompanyA].dbo.InvMaster i ON  c.StockCode = i.StockCode
  WHERE Deleted = 'False'
) c
WHERE c.StockCode='000-256966-020'
  AND rn <= 10
GROUP BY c.StockCode,c.LongDesc,c.BomWeightKG
ORDER BY c.StockCode DESC
```